# Best case for sending and receiving messages in MPI in a ring form

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, shared-memory, distributed-computing

I wanted to ask about the answer to the following question

For this MPI program segment that performs a communication by having each process send a
value, n, to the process next to it in a ring pattern. That is, if there are N processes, then Process 0
will send the value to 1, Process 1 will send to 2, and so on. The last process will send its value
to 0. These messages will all happen one time in parallel.

```
  if (my_rank%2 == 0) { MPI_SEND(msg,size,MPI_INT,(my_rank+1)%comm_sz,0,comm);

    MPI_RECV(new_msg,size,MPI_INT,(my_rank+comm_sz-1)%comm_sz,0,comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); } 

else  {

    MPI_RECV(new_msg,size,MPI_INT,(my_rank+comm_sz-1)%comm_sz,0,comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    MPI_SEND(msg,size,MPI_INT,(my_rank+1)%comm_sz,0,comm); }
```

Assume that the time to send a message is one time unit, and the time to receive a
message is one time unit. Include only the cost for the messaging (ignore any startup
costs, etc.) and calculate, in the best case, how many time units it will take for your code
to complete. You should state any assumptions that you make explicitly.

what I thought that it would be 4, in the best case if all of the even sent n at the same time and all of the odds received at the same time here is 2 and for the odd sending the same so another 2 so it would be 4 but I don't know if I am right or not

Answer (score 1):

you'd rather use `MPI_Sendrecv()`
this will avoid you having to deal with odd vs even ranks.

keep in mind that generally speaking `MPI_Send()` returns immediately when sending small messages, whereas it blocks until a matching `MPI_Recv()` is posted if the message is large. A correct MPI program should expect `MPI_Send()` always block until a matching `MPI_Recv()` is posted.

Comment: Thank you I'd take care of that, but for this question and this code since they are givens is what I thought about for the time cost right or not ?
Thanks again.